# TomEE ++ and ObjectDB can not get it work

Tags: java, apache-tomee, objectdb

I have a DaoService which gets initialized when the app starts.

```
public DaoService() {
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "admin");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "admin");
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/db/points.odb", properties);
    //exception!
}
```

But everytime it fires this exception:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "$objectdb/db/points.odb" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl, com.objectdb.jpa.Provider from provider: com.objectdb.jpa.Provider
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1028)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1375)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "$objectdb/db/points.odb" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl, com.objectdb.jpa.Provider from provider: com.objectdb.jpa.Provider
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:291)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "$objectdb/db/points.odb" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl, com.objectdb.jpa.Provider from provider: com.objectdb.jpa.Provider
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:363)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:283)
    at $Proxy110.loginUser(Unknown Source)
    at net.heatboxes.core.service.AuthorizationService.logIn(AuthorizationService.java:42)
    at net.heatboxes.core.bean.view.Login.submit(Login.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "$objectdb/db/points.odb" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl, com.objectdb.jpa.Provider from provider: com.objectdb.jpa.Provider
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:244)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:186)
    at net.heatboxes.dao.DaoService.<init>(DaoService.java:42)
    at net.heatboxes.dao.DaoService.getInstance(DaoService.java:27)
    at net.heatboxes.core.service.StatelessService.getDaoService(StatelessService.java:22)
    at net.heatboxes.core.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.loginUser(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
    at net.heatboxes.core.interseptors.AccessControlInterceptor.interceptor(AccessControlInterceptor.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.invoke(CdiInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.access$000(CdiInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor$1.call(CdiInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.aroundInvoke(CdiInterceptor.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:176)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:138)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateful.StatefulContainer.businessMethod(StatefulContainer.java:673)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateful.StatefulContainer.invoke(StatefulContainer.java:378)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:246)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:241)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:279)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.objectdb.o._PersistenceException: Failed to validate xml file C:\!heatboxes-web\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml: 
    at com.objectdb.o._PersistenceException.b(_PersistenceException.java:45)
    at com.objectdb.jpa.Provider.createEntityManagerFactory(Provider.java:87)
    at com.objectdb.jpa.Provider.createEntityManagerFactory(Provider.java:32)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: com.objectdb.o.UserException: Failed to validate xml file C:\!heatboxes-web\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml: 
    at com.objectdb.o.MSG.d(MSG.java:74)
    at com.objectdb.o.XMD.n(XMD.java:217)
    at com.objectdb.o.XMD.k(XMD.java:155)
    at com.objectdb.o.UNM$z._e(UNM.java:182)
    at com.objectdb.o.UNM$z.<init>(UNM.java:169)
    at com.objectdb.o.UNM.x(UNM.java:105)
    at com.objectdb.o.UNM.w(UNM.java:75)
    at com.objectdb.jpa.Provider.createEntityManagerFactory(Provider.java:56)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:623)
    at com.objectdb.o.XMD.n(XMD.java:200)
    ... 88 more
```

I tried with and without this persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

   <persistence-unit name="my-pu">
     <description>My Persistence Unit</description>
     <provider>com.objectdb.jpa.Provider</provider>


     <class>net.heatboxes.dao.entity.UserEntity</class>
     <properties>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                 value="my.odb"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
     </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Created new thread on ObjectDB forum http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/649

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've got it. I should not use any persistence.xml at all. When I do not use it, I got this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - 
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or
>   DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName
>   property. Available properties in configuration are
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@fdaf18ee".

openjpa conflicts with existing JPA of my objectdb.jar.

To avoid it, I removed `openjpa-asm-shaded-`X.X.X`.jar` from my TomEE`/lib` folder.

---

### Summarize

**Only:**

> Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/db/painInTheAss.odb");

for EntityManagerFactory

**Only:**

> objectdb-ee.jar

for objectdb library in dependencies.

**Only without:**

> openjpa-asm-shaded-X.X.X.jar

in TomEE`/lib`

---

Netbeans could still create persistance.xml for you which will break everything.
if you still not successful and use NetBeans, clear its cache, in `C:\Users\`YOURNAME`\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache`

You may look in YOURPROJECT`\nbproject\project.properties` to see some old malformed settings you played around and leaved as it is.